# How to return a string to the main int function?

Tags: c++

Here is my code(C++) below... I am confused on how to return the username I retrieved in `getusername` back to the main function. Does anyone have nay tips or suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
//For the strings obviously
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string getusername();
string user;


string getusername() {
    user = system("echo %username% > NUL");
    return user;
}



int main() {
    string getname;
    getname = getusername();
    cout << "Hello: "<< getname << endl;
}
```

Comment: I am using Visual Studio and it returned no errors... The output never returns the user name though... It just says `Hello: ` and leaves out the username.

Comment: You should read about what the [`std::system()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function actually does

Comment: Do you want to get the value of the environment variable `%username%`? Check for [`std::getenv()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) then.

Comment: @user0042 it says getenv is unsafe, try using `dupenv` instead.

Comment: `getenv()` is perfectly fine for your usecase.

Comment: Why use getenv if it is deprecated though?

Comment: I can't spot any _deprecation_ from that linked reference?

Comment: Mhm, Visual Studios wont even let me run it...

Comment: Microsoft may have stuck an underscore on the front. Try `_getenv`. And there might be a `getenv_s`. Microsoft loves those _s functions. See what's out there with your favourite search engine.

Comment: @NerdOfCode What do you want to achieve with that code? Is my assumption that you want to retrieve the environment variable value correct? If so, make that clear in your question please.

Comment: Yes, I want to retrieve the current logged on user...

Comment: @NerdOfCode And what's your specific problem with `getenv("USERNAME")`, can you clarify that also please? [edit]

Comment: Visual Studios would not let me run that... It says its consider using  `_dupenv_s` instead

Comment: @NerdOfCode Provide a [MCVE] in your question regarding that please. Just mentioning is futile in trying to get a good answer regarding that specific problem. Also if your specific compiler requires to use `_dupenv_s()` instead, why not simply doing that? It might be about Unicode aware system functions in that case.

Comment: Finally I fixed the issue. I used `#pragma warning(disable:4996)` to suppress the genenv insecure error, and now I retrieve the username using `getenv("USERNAME");`

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement should work. However,

```
user = system("echo %username% > NUL");
```

is a problem. See [documentation of `std::system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) to understand what it does.

If you want the user to input the value of `usre`, you have two options. If you want the value of `user` to be without whitespace, you can use:

```
std::cout >> user;
```

If you want the value of `user` to contain an entire line of text, whitespace and all, use:

```
std::getline(std:::cout, user);
```

If you want to use get the value of the environment variable `USERNAME`, use [`std::getenv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv).

```
user = std::getenv("USERNAME");
```

Comment: Where exactly would I implement `getline`?

Comment: @NerdOfCode It's absolutely unclear what you want to achieve at all.

Comment: @NerdOfCode, `std::getline` is a standard library function. You don't need to implement it. You just use it.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

> Return Value
>
> If command is a null pointer, the function returns a non-zero value in case a command processor is available and a zero value if it is not.
>
> If command is not a null pointer, the value returned depends on the system and library implementations, but it is generally expected to be the status code returned by the called command, if supported.

If you want to run a system command and catch the output you can use popen.

A simple example could look like this.

```
std::string exec(const std::string& cmd) {
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"), pclose);
    if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    while (fgets(buffer.data(), 128, pipe.get()) != nullptr)
        result += buffer.data();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please don't refer to that buggy and unreliable reference. en.cppreference.com is way better than this.

Comment: @user4581301 In your link the final example uses the same idea as in my code, even though writte slightly different. Check if .get() gives EOF and then also verify the data read before appending it to the result. I don't see the problem?

Comment: @super The same concept would be `while(fgets(buffer.data(), 128, pipe.get()) != nullptr)`

Comment: I owe you an apology. Your code is checking for read success. At worst you are (Well, were now) guilty of an extra check.

Comment: Just noticed something odd. I wonder why `std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"), pclose);` works when with a `unique_ptr` you'd have to `std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&fclose)> pipe(file, fclose);` What extra voodoo is `shared_ptr` hiding?

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointer out, the std::system call is not interactive, meaning you cannot read/write from/to the shell.

I have implemented a nice popen() wrapper for Posix compliant operating systems that allows users easily interact with the shell, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/dtrugman/ModernPosix).

Here is a usage example:

```
try {
    mp::ipstream reader("ls -l");

    vector<string> output;
    reader >> output;
}
catch (std::runtime_error & ex) {
    // Something went wrong and ex.what() will tell you what it is
}
```

This library contains more such wrappers and you are more than welcome to use them if they suit your needs.